# Should I use Polymorphic association for this scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models. `Jobs`, `Businesses`, & `Categories`.

`Jobs` have many `categories`.

`Businesses` have many `categories`.

`Categories` have many `jobs`.

`Categories` have many `businesses`.

Is a polymorphic association the most appropriate for this scenario?

---

*category.rb*

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :categorised, polymorphic: true
end
```

*business.rb*

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, as: :categorised
end
```

*job.rb*

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, as: :categorised
end
```

Comment: You should do polymorphic association. Category models are usually same for all relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will depend on how much commonality there is between the `Job` and `Business` objects. If they mostly have the same attributes, then yes, it may make sense to store them in the same table.

But in either case, you've got a many-to-many relationship: `Jobs` have many `Categories`, and `Categories` have many `Jobs`.  That's going to call for a `:has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with a join table linking the two.

Answer (score 0):

i would advise you habtm relationship

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   has_and_belongs_to_many :business
   has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
end
```

business.rb

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```